# Scroll to iframe popup element

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, parent, scrollto

I have Javascript / jQuery widget in iframe.

Whenever user register or make some actions in widget there will be confirmation popup open to user in center of iframe. My iframe has no scrollbar.

It's height is auto resizable according to content in iframe.

Problem is that when i was at bottom of my register page(Submit button) in iframe and when i click on submit and open success message to user at and user will see only half popup or sometime it is above the current window so user can not see the popup message.My widget is responsive.
So i want to scroll to opened popup.

See below image :
[image]

My iframe code. Here i am taking top positionof popup divide by 2 and send a postmessage to parent window.

```
scroll_at = Math.abs($("#RegisterPopup").offset().top)/2;
window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"scroll_at": scroll_at}), "*");
```

In Parent window (3rd Party Website), I am getting this scroll position and scroll it.

```
window.scrollTo(0,obj.scroll_at);
```

> Above code is working perfect. But I am unable to get perfect position of
>   popup.

How should i get top height of popup from current window to iframe popup so i can scroll to popup?

Comment: try fiddle. try position relative some 10%

Comment: @raghavendra i am unable to get it. can you give more details?

Comment: @YatinMistry, are you resolve the issue? If so, how? Having the same problem.

Comment: No i don't have resolved the issue

Comment: @Juriy whenever you resolve issue, post your solution here

Comment: @YatinMistry , I recognized , that from iframe it could be controlling just it's own window, not external one. For particular task on centartion scroll bar on popup I expluatate messages between windows like so 'window.parent.sendMessage(.)' as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357553/is-absolute-positioning-valuable-for-scroll-to-the-element-when-one-appears