# Is absolute positioning valuable for scroll to the element when one appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, sweetalert

I'm using `sweetalert` modal dialog. It is positioned to center of screen as I understand. But when I use it  inside `iframe element (by URL) it appears in the center of built-in document, and as result not seen in view area.

I've tried to use `position: absolute` style on modal, it has not obvious influence:

1. it is positioned as before, on the center of built-in document (why :\ ?)
2. it is 'ensured' to seen on the view area as following: if modal rect not intersected with view area rect at all, browser scrolls to the modal immediately. But if modal rect at some point intersects view area rect (for instance, just bottom side of modal dialog seen) browser's scroll stays at the previous position.

What is the reason of the jump to the dialog ? Is it absolute positioning or something else?

Comment: try to add the modal style `position:relative` and then in the modal add your alert context with position absolute.

Comment: The "built-in-document" is aware only its own `window` object and its positioning, and everything is positioned related to document's own `window`. You have calculate the top-left corner of the modal using top-left corner of the iframe element related to its container window.

Comment: @Teemu, does browser scrolling to modal (to be "ensure visible"), when I have calculated position of top-left corner of modal ? That is the goal, to get modal "ensured visible".

Comment: @ShoaibZafar, modal appends to the last element on the document, after the overlay. Trick you advised not worked. But thanks, it was new to me.

Comment: As the resolution I want to add `window.parent.postMessage` and handle it in parent element. It will ensured that my modal will be in the view port area (visible for user).